# Highcharts horizontal bar chart categories are sized incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm having a problem with Highcharts where each bar chart category is way too tall in a horizontal arrangement.

Here is an example:

[image: An example of an incorrectly sized category]

The code used to generate the chart is as follows:

```
chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'wordchart1',
          defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Word Frequency Distribution'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['LIL POP SHOP','SWEET BOX','LITTLE BABY\'S ICE CREAM','SUGAR PHILLY','Please pick one:'              ],
          title: {
            text: ''
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'Word Frequency Analysis',
            align: 'high'
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Word Frequency Analysis',
          data: [89,43,32,24,3              ]              }]
        });
      });
```

Any idea what may be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/xwG5S/

Comment: What's the height on your container div?

Comment: If your height is explicitly set, make sure that the container div is "visible" (aka not display: none; or in a display: none; element) when you initialize the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define pointWidth: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointWidth